# ¿Como se puede agregar padding top y button a los options de la etiqueta select?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```html
<label>Selecciona</label>
<select class="form-control">
<option value="">Si</option>
<option value="">No</option>
</select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes remover los estilos por defecto que un elemento select tiene mediante la propiedad

```css
appearance: none;
```

Luego, puedes editar los estilos como necesites.
Comparto código ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container {
      padding: 16px;
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid;
      width: 500px;
      height: 300px;
    }

    .custom-select {
      appearance: none;
      width: 60px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(194, 194, 194);
      border-radius: 0.25em;
      padding: 8px 16px;
      font-size: 24px;
      cursor: pointer;
      line-height: 32px;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <body class="sec">
    <h1>Custom Select</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <label>Selecciona</label>
      <select class="custom-select">
        <option value="">Si</option>
        <option value="">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <script></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pero el padding no figura en la etiqueta option

Comment: En tal caso, entiendo que no es posible afectar los elementos option con css directamente. Esto también se discutió acá: [How to style the option of an html “select” element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

No obstante, puedes intentar crear un select personalizado. 
Comparto un ejemplo:

[Select personalizado](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select)